# Geração procedural

Tags: jogos

Em jogos como minecraft,cube world e starbound existe o termo "Mapa proceduralmente gerado".Conforme você anda durante o jogo,o mapa é criado,mas com uma "seed" que sempre irá gerar o mesmo mapa.

Como é possível usar um pequeno conjunto de caracteres para determinar a criação de mapas padronizados,com colinas,havinas,minérios e outros features sempre no mesmo local(baseado na mesma seed)?

Comment: Pergunta bacana. :) A sua inspiração foi essa thread no Gamedev? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/18840/36442

Comment: O que vc quis dizer com pequeno conjunto de caracteres? Geralmente mapas procedurais são gerados com _perlin noise_, ou outros algoritmos que dêem sempre o mesmo resultado quando alimentados com as mesmas variáveis (além da _seed_). Você pode usar algoritmos diferentes, ou do mesmo resultado usar diferentes partes da informação para determinar a altura do terreno, o material, se tem árvore ou não. Coisas "móveis" como água, dependem um pouco de você armazenar dados se quiser algum tipo de persistência (o user mexe no cenário e encontra as coisas como deixou).

Comment: @LuizVieira eu ainda não acompanho o stack em inglês.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basicamente os desenvolvedores de jogos quando utilizam Seeds, eles usam geradores de Hashes.

**Geradores de Hashes:** Geram uma mesma sequencia de caracteres com base numa palavra curta.

Com os hashes gerados eles podem gerar outros hashes encadeados que vão definir outros pontos do jogo iguais á semente (seed)

Para a geração de mapas e relevos o algoritmo que mais vi ser usado foi o **Perlin noise**, que incluse gera uma mesmo relevo com base numa seed e este foi inclusive o algoritmo originalmente utilizado nos mapas pelo criador de Minecraft.

Como criar um gerador de hash?
A principio é relativamente simples, desde que ele deva sempre gerar o mesmo resultado com base num mesmo valor de entrada, pode ser uma simples função matemática.

Por exemplo, uma logica de hash usando seeds numéricas poderia ser:
seed = (seed x 31337) + 123

[Exemplo Hash Algoritmn (Ingles)](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/encryption5.htm)

Answer (score 6):

<sup>**Atenção: Estas não é uma resposta, apenas um complemento à resposta de Rogerio Barreto.**</sup>

Exemplo prático de geração procedural, utilizando *seeding*:

```
var seed = 25; //Escolha um valor numérico positivo e inteiro qualquer.

var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

    if (canvas.getContext){

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0,100);

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            //Vamos usar a fórmula do Rogério Barreto
            seed = ((seed * 31337) + 123) % 100;
            ctx.lineTo(i * 10, 100 + ((seed - 50) / 5));
        }

        ctx.lineTo(1000, 200);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 200);

        ctx.fillStyle="green";
        ctx.fill();
    }
```

Resultado para diferentes valores:

25 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
19 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
91 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Brinque com este código no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3z9pbuce/)

Comment: Muito bom exemplo ! Bom te ver aqui meu caro ! Abraço!

Comment: @RogerioBarreto Posso dizer o mesmo! Abraços! =)